# Jest test don't identify the test id in react web app

Tags: reactjs, testing, input, jestjs, vite

I'm doing a react web test using Jest, but the Jest don't identify the test id (i'm using vite, i don't know if is a problem). I tried verify by placeholder, but not success to (i think it could cause more problems, because i'm using i18)
Error:
[image: Error Unable to find an element by]

```
const mockStore = configureStore([]);
describe("LinkAccountFormDialog", () => {
  it("successfully links an account", async () => {
    const initialState = {
      session: {
        sessionUser: { uid: "testUserId" },
      },
    };
    const store = mockStore(initialState);

    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <LinkAccountFormDialog onFinished={() => {}} />
        </I18nextProvider>
      </Provider>
    );

    fireEvent.change(getByTestId("username-input"), {
      target: { value: "testUsername" },
    });
    fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText("Password"), {
      target: { value: "testPassword" },
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId('username-input').value).toBe('testUsername');
    }, { timeout: 5000 });  // Aumente o timeout conforme necessário.
  });
});
```

Input camp:

```
<Input
          data-testid="username-input"
          placeholder={t("general.username")}
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
```

Comment: Is the `input` element you are talking about, is inside this compoent `LinkAccountFormDialog`? If so, is it a component that conditionally rendrered?

Comment: The main component is a modal, the flux: open modal -> select an account OR click in login button IF you click in the login button, the next stap is login in LinkAccountFormDialog, in the same modal

Comment: i think this is a conditional render, right?

Comment: If the modal is rendered conditionally and initially not being rendered- then the elements you try to capture are yet to exist